# Not getting error from async method in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use the following code

```
require('./ut/valid').validateFile()

});
```

in the validate file when I found some duplicate in config I send error 
like following

```
module.exports = {
    validateFile: function (req) {
...
if(dup){
console.log("Duplicate found: ");
return new Error("Duplicate found: ");
}
```

dup is true and the error should be thrown, how should I **"catch"** it in async method ?

I tried also like following

```
require('./ut/valid').validateFile(function() {
    process.exit(1);
});
```

what I miss here, I was able to see the console log...

Comment: 1.) you throw error with throw keyword, 2.) it will not work with async code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach doens't work because you're doing something asynchronous. A common solution is to use `callbacks`. In node.js it's common to use a pattern called [error first callbacks](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/).

This means you need to pass a `callback` function to your file validation method and either return an error or your file:

```
  // './utils/validate.js'
  module.exports = {

    /**
     * Validates a file.
     *
     * @param {Function} next - callback function that either exposes an error or the file in question
     */
    file: function (next) {
      // ...

      if (duplicate) {
        console.log('Duplicate found!');

        var error = new Error('Duplicate File');
        // Perhaps enrich the error Object.

        return next(error);
      }

      // Eveything is ok, return the file.
      next(null, file);
    }
};
```

The you can use it like this:

```
 // './app.js'
var validate = require('./utils/validate');

validate.file(function (err, file) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error.
    process.exit(1);
  }

  // Everything is ok, use the file.
  console.log('file: ', file);
});
```

Comment: Thanks 1+and how should I call to validate file and catch the error, can you please update the answer with this code?

Comment: @JhonDree is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much knowledge in node, but I can tell you, you are returning an error object, which is not an error from JS perspective, it's just an object, to get an error you have to throw an error like:

```
throw true;
```

or

```
throw new Error("Duplicate found: ");
```

that way it is handled as an error not as a return value